# Is there a way to set the camera output to be one frame?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to simulate a "*lost connection*" scenario for a security camera.
I'd like to **set the camera output to the last frame registered** before the disconnection event, but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to have a function running in the background checking for the connection (event tick?) and whenever it registers that the connection is lost you need to notify and take that screenshot like this:
[How to Screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z84A.png)